# Docker web and apis refusing connection

Tags: laravel, api, docker, docker-compose, lumen

I'm pretty new to docker. I have created a docker-compose which has 1 main app (laravel) site, and 2 apis.

I am trying to access the apis from the laravel site, but keep getting:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8082: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:1.10
    volumes:
    - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
    - app
    restart: always

  app:
    build: . #run the dockerfile to install whatever
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
    - database

  web-api2:
    image: nginx:1.10
    volumes:
    - ../api/api2/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8081:81"
    depends_on:
    - app-api2

  app-api2:
    build: . #run the dockerfile to install whatever
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
    - ../api/api2:/var/www
    depends_on:
    - database

  web-api1:
    image: nginx:1.10
    volumes:
    - ../api/api1/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
    - "8082:82"
    depends_on:
    - app-api1

  app-api1:
    build: . #run the dockerfile to install whatever
    env_file: ../api/api1/.env
    volumes:
    - ../api/api1:/var/www
    depends_on:
    - database

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=IAmSoSecure"
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=my_app"
    ports:
    - "33061:3306"
    volumes:
    - my_app:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always


volumes:
  wildfire:
```

I've looked into docker networking but my attempts have failed. I have a network setup, and the tried using the subnets but it didn't do the trick:

```
"IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I have tried accessing the ports I enabled too:

```
"Ports": {
            "443/tcp": null,
            "80/tcp": null,
            "82/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8082"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I am requesting the call as per usual via Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('127.0.0.1:8082/accounts');
dd($res->getBody()->getContents());
```

I have tried different IPs but can't find the correct one to use.

My Current vhost.conf is:

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php server.php;
root /var/www/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html server.php index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}

location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` again?

Comment: Turning it off, and on again doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately. lol...

Comment: Since you are using port 8082 I assume you have one container trying to contact `app-api2`. Try replacing `127.0.0.1` with `app-api2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the default network that docker compose creates, each container managed by the orchestrator is reachable by it's service name that happens to be identical to the name given to it in the `docker-compose.yaml` file. So in your case each container on the same network may reach `app-api2` as your question details with:

```
http://app-api2:82/accounts
```

For a more complete answer using `127.0.0.1` from within your container means that you are trying to reach a service that is within the container itself and listening on, in your case, `82`. Since you have no other executables running within the same container and listening on that port you are correctly receiving `Connection refused`.

It may also be useful for you to know that you do not strictly **need** to expose the ports from your `docker-compose.yaml` file for other containers on the same network to communicate. The exposed ports enable you make requests from the host machine (where in fact you would use `127.0.0.1`).

If for whatever reason you do want to use the IP address of the container to communicate between containers than you can find the current IP for a specific container using `docker inspect <container name>`. However note that this IP is ephemeral and will likely change each time the container is spun up.

More detailed information can be found https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking

Comment: Would this also be impacting on trying to load CSS or public assets into the webpage? As this seems to be an issue now... 

GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/adminlte/dist/css/skins/skin-yellow-light.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
accounts:11 GET http://localhost:8080/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
accounts:10 GET http://localhost:8080/vendor/adminlte/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I can only assume nginx cannot see my public, or storage directory?

Comment: The nginx container is probably not mounting your static assets. However it is difficult to tell how this has been setup without seeing the nginx config

Comment: Added my current vhost.conf to the original question

Answer (score 2):

On your docker compose, you launch 3 nginx: web, web-api2 and web-api1.

From what you write, web-api2 listen on port 81 and web-api1 on port 82.

If you want from application in **web** to access api, you will need to use:

```
http://web-api2:81/...
http://web-api1:82/...
```

Note that from your **local computer**, you will use `http://localhost:8081` and `http://localhost:8082` as you map port 8081 to 81 on web-api2 and 8082 to 82 on web-api1.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue I changed the url I was looking at to:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('**http://web-api2:82/accounts**');
dd($res->getBody()->getContents());
```

I also changed the port number to 8082 for best practice. This is reflected in my docker-compose.yml too so:

```
web 8080:8080
web-api1 8081:8081
web-api2 8082:8082
```

Thanks to all for your answers!